# How to set cpumask at boot with systemd?

Tags: bash, centos7, systemd

I have the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=foo

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/opt/script/bar.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And `bar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1 > /sys/bus/workqueue/devices/writeback/cpumask
cat /sys/bus/workqueue/devices/writeback/cpumask > /tmp/writeback
```

Then after I rebooted, `cat /tmp/writeback` looks good:
`000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001`

But `/sys/bus/workqueue/devices/writeback/cpumask` got overwritten back to default:

```
ffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
```

Thought?

Comment: Be aware that a malicious local user might create a symlink from `/tmp/writeback` to `/etc/passwd` or `/sbin/init` and deny service to users. The output file should be created in a directory writable only by root.

Comment: @AndersonMedeirosGomes thanks.  was trying to debug only.  will fix.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe use ExecStart instead of ExecStop?

Comment: That's fine according to the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).  And `/tmp/writeback` was written and so we know the `/opt/script/bar.sh` had been executed (successfully).

Comment: in the link you send you can clearly read: "Commands to execute to stop the service started via ExecStart=.", so it's never going to run after starting the service. Only after stopping it, and only if it had successfully started. I just tried, when you start the service, it does nothing but the service starts (doing nothing), when you stop the service, the command runs, and the file gets written, and the value of cpumask gets set to 1